# Crontab Opens Headless Terminal When Starting A Minecraft Server

Tags: ubuntu, cron, minecraft

I'm using crontab on Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS to run a Minecraft server at 7 am everyday,the problem is that crontab runs the command to run the Minecraft server but without opening a visible terminal.

If crontab can open visible terminals this is my code.
`0 7 * * * cd /home/pokepuff05/Desktop/ScoutcraftC2 && java -server -Xms512M -Xmx16G -XX:+UseG1GC -jar fabric1.19.3sever.jar nogui`
If crontab only runs headless programs could you link me an alternative to crontab?

Thank you in advance

Comment: What you're describing is possible to do in cron, ([example](https://askubuntu.com/questions/514167/how-to-start-a-gui-application-from-cron)) but way more trouble than it's worth. There are a few directions you could go. 1) You could log the output of the program to a file by adding `>> /path/to/log.txt 2>&1` to the command. 2) You could open a terminal, and use a Bash while loop to repeatedly run the command, then sleep until the next morning.  Both of those would avoid needing to launch a GUI app from crontab.